# Ruby block - return yield running code after yield

Tags: ruby, yield, ruby-block

I want to return the output of `yield` but also execute the code after `yield`, is there a more "right" way?:

```
def myblock
  yield_output = yield
  puts 'after yield'
  yield_output
end

myblock {'my yield'}
# after yield
#  => my yield
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
def myblock
  yield.tap { puts 'after yield' }
end

myblock { 'my yield' }
# after yield
#=> my yield
```

Comment: thanks thought there would be something more ruby elegant

Comment: was just typing that...you can use parens if you want to yield an argument `(yield 5).tap { puts 'after yield' }`.

Comment: @SimpleLime although `yield` is not a method, I'd put the parentheses around the argument(s), i.e. `yield(5).tap { ... }`, but either way works.

Comment: @joshweir in case you need the result (`'my yield'`) in your code: `tap` passes the receiver to the block, so you can write `yield.tap { |result| ... }`